# Can't access GUI mode with Virtual Box fresh 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, apt, virtualbox, sudo

Trying to install 12.04 in virtual box. Install went great after restart I get a white error box talking about my graphics. Basically I get options to look at different log files or I can run without the GUI.

I logged in via terminal and then did a `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install update`. The first one worked but the second one gives the error *unable to locate package update*.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is ok, because the **second** command that you are entering is wrong.

It is `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead of `sudo apt-get install update`.

When you enter `sudo apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME` you are trying to install a package, but there is no package called `update`

Normally, to update the system, we enter both command in one instance:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: To also get kernel fixes (and other updates) that may be needed to run Ubuntu in VBox it often is better to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.